# Ms Project: Compensation for a worker

Tags: ms-project

I'll go straigth to the point. We need to represent on MS Project the payment of a compensation for an accident to one worker in particular and only that one. But we can't figure out how to do it!

We are kind of new to this software (and actually are only using it for a colleage assigment). We have two separated files, one for the task and another one for our resources. We've searched everywhere on the infromation of the resoruce in the Resoruces file but could not find anything.

Any idea? Thank you very much for reading and, please, forgive me if my English is kind of messy sometimes, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of a workaround, but if you go to your Resource Sheet view and double click on the resource, you can go to the Costs tab and enter a new rate (probably distributed over an 8 hour day) effective on the day of the payment, then add a third rate effective the day after the payment which is the same as the original. It should have the same effect.